# ¿Cómo leer un archivo por partes y convirtiéndolo en bytes con java?

Tags: java

necesito convertir un archivo grande a bytes (al menos 5GiB) para enviarlo mediante Rest, sin embargo, al intentar convertir el archivo a bytes, el proceso se muere debido a la longitud del archivo. Para solucionar este problema, he pensando en leer el archivo por partes e ir almacenando esas partes en un byte array, sin embargo, no sé como leer un archivo por partes. Si me pudieran dar una pista, se los agradecería demasiado.

Answer (score 1):

Esto te puede ayudar en parte ya que te permite ir leyendo el archivo y cuando tengas leidos 1 MiB, o la última lectura haya cargado en el buffer de lectura menos del tamaño de este (esto indicaría que ya no hay más datos que leer y que la próxima iteración no entrará al código del bucle), enviarlo al servidor.

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("ruta/al/archivo/de/5GiB");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[1024];
    int readed = -1;
    while ((readed = inputStream.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
        baos.write(BUFFER, 0, readed);

        /*
         * Cuando se haya leido 1 MiB del archivo, o se la lectura actual haya 
         * leido menos del tamaño del buffer de lectura, enviarlo al servidor
         */
        if (baos.size() == 1024000 || readed < 1024) {
            sendToRestService(baos.toByteArray());
            baos.reset();
        }
    }
```

Puedes cambiar la cantidad de bytes que quieres enviar al servidor modificando el valor (en este caso el 1024000) con que se compara el tamaño actual del `ByteArrayOutputStream` donde vas almacenando los datos leidos.

He omitido la captura de excepciones y el código que cierra los streams pero debes agregarlo tu, o bien utilizar un try-with-resources.